# oCanvas object dynamic render order

Tags: javascript, rendering, ocanvas

I'm trying to get a dynamic rendering order going in ocanvas but can't find any information in the docs about how to go about doing it.  I want something along the lines of "the object's y position affects the order in which it is rendered", it's for an isometric game engine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing automatic for this, but you can probably implement it quite easily with the `zIndex` property: http://ocanvas.org/docs/Display-Objects/Base#property-zIndex

Comment: Hi Johannes, I tried that but it didn't work.  I tried making the zindex of the object equal to its y position.  perhaps I'm not using it correctly?

Comment: it seems that no matter what they are rendered in the order they are added to the canvas

Comment: The `zIndex` property is a real index for the object in the list of children for its parent, which means you can't use the `y` value directly, but you can convert it to get the index you want. I made an example here (drag around the rectangles to try it): http://jsfiddle.net/ky3z7mjg/